# Angular multiple directive elements with same parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can one do this?

I've provided a Fiddle to demonstrate my problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/FCAJD/

```
myApp.directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<ul ng-transclude></ul>'
    }
});

myApp.directive('tab', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<li>test</li>'
    }
});
```

And the html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <tabs>
      <tab />
      <tab />
      <tab />
      <tab />
  </tabs>
</div>
```

Essentially, I want "test" to show up multiple times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly terminate the directives.

So instead of:

```
<tab /> 
...
```

You want:

```
<tab></tab>
...
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCAJD/3/)

You can see this related [Angular github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953).  With this comment from one of the Angular folks (Igor Minar):

> self-closing or void elements as the html spec defines them are very
>   special to the browser parser. you can't make your own, so for your
>   custom elements you have to stick to non-void elements (`<foo></foo>`).

Comment: JEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEZZZ *slaps self* Thank you! I have no valid reason why I didn't attempt to do that (except that i didn't really have many reasons to believe it was the self closing aspect causing the problem)